# Text editors show python created UTF-8 files as gibberish

Tags: python, file, unicode, encoding, save

this is my first question here and if its format is not what is expected here, sorry in advance.

I have a small utility that reads ISO-8859-9 text files and produces its UTF-8 copies. The method I found is the usage of encode and decode methods, when I implement the way of the elders, text editors show the unicode characters as irrelevant characters.

The twist of the problem is the files are written correctly. For check, I've created a hand-created version of the same file in TextEdit in Mac. The converted version's hex dump and md5sum is same for the hand-created one. However both Textedit and Kwrite (or Kate) on KDE shows absurd characters even if I choose UTF-8 as the input encoding. Why this is happening and how can I solve this?

Thanks a lot.

Update:

od -c outputs are below:

First of all, the ISO-8859-9 file:

```
0000000  374 360   i 376 347 366 334 320 335 336 307 326   T   e   s   t
0000020    T   e   s   t                                                
0000024
```

The Python Created UTF-8:

```
0000000    ü  **   ğ  **   i   ş  **   ç  **   ö  **   Ü  **   Ğ  **   İ
0000020   **   Ş  **   Ç  **   Ö  **   T   e   s   t   T   e   s   t    
0000037
```

Hand Created UTF-8:

```
0000000    ü  **   ğ  **   i   ş  **   ç  **   ö  **   Ü  **   Ğ  **   İ
0000020   **   Ş  **   Ç  **   Ö  **   T   e   s   t   T   e   s   t    
0000037
```

The Actual Code:

```
def convert_file(path_of_text_file):
    try:
        original_file = open(path_of_text_file, 'rb')
        file_contents = unicode(original_file.read(), 'iso-8859-9')
        original_file.close()

        new_file = open("untitled2.txt", 'w+b')
        new_file.write(file_contents.encode('utf8'))
        new_file.close()
    except IOError:
        pass
```

Also yes, the handcrafted file open just fine. Also it has the same md5sum and hex output of the python generated one.

od -xc outputs:

Again the original ISO-8859-9 file:

```
0000000      f0fc    fe69    f6e7    d0dc    dedd    d6c7    6554    7473
         374 360   i 376 347 366 334 320 335 336 307 326   T   e   s   t
0000020      6554    7473                                                
           T   e   s   t                                                
0000024
```

Python generated UTF-8 file:

```
0000000      bcc3    9fc4    c569    c39f    c3a7    c3b6    c49c    c49e
           ü  **   ğ  **   i   ş  **   ç  **   ö  **   Ü  **   Ğ  **   İ
0000020      c5b0    c39e    c387    5496    7365    5474    7365    0074
          **   Ş  **   Ç  **   Ö  **   T   e   s   t   T   e   s   t    
0000037
```

Hand crafted UTF-8 file:

```
0000000      bcc3    9fc4    c569    c39f    c3a7    c3b6    c49c    c49e
           ü  **   ğ  **   i   ş  **   ç  **   ö  **   Ü  **   Ğ  **   İ
0000020      c5b0    c39e    c387    5496    7365    5474    7365    0074
          **   Ş  **   Ç  **   Ö  **   T   e   s   t   T   e   s   t    
0000037
```

Another note of interest: BBEdit handles python created files just fine.

Comment: Show some `od -c` output for both files.

Comment: Show some code, as well as input/output.

Comment: If you save the handcrafted file, close the program, and reopen it, does it still show up properly?

Comment: Better, show some `od -xc` output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved the problem. This is a mixed issue of OSX resource forks, TextEdit and a bit of PEBKAC. Here's how I solved it:

I copied the files to my (fat32) flash disk, so I get the resource forks as ".filename" . The thing I noticed that the file I wrote with python has come with no resource forks. Interestingly when I opened file from the flash disk with TextEdit with forced UTF-8 encoding, everything worked fine (strangely it didn't work when I tried before copying files to the flash).

With this evidence I can say that TextEdit is storing a file's encoding in its resource fork, not guessing it everytime unlike the file command. More interestingly now my Linux boxen seems to behave well, I can't say why.

As a result, the code works as it should and everything is fine. The dud is the TextEdit, not python.

Thanks everyone,

Happy hacking.

Comment: @SilentStorm I appreciate your mention of PEBKAC as part of your troubleshooting.

Answer (score 0):

I did a quick implementation of what I presume your Python conversion script is doing:

```
iso = "\374\360i\376\347\366\334\320\335\336\307\326Test Test"
tmp = iso.decode('iso-8859-9')
utf = tmp.encode('utf-8')
out = open('utf.txt', 'wb')
out.write(utf)
```

The `od -xc` output:

```
0000000    bcc3    9fc4    c569    c39f    c3a7    c3b6    c49c    c49e
        303 274 304 237   i 305 237 303 247 303 266 303 234 304 236 304
0000020    c5b0    c39e    c387    5496    7365    2074    6554    7473
        260 305 236 303 207 303 226   T   e   s   t       T   e   s   t
0000040
```

Screenshots from Textedit in Mac:

[image: Textedit input encoding pref pane]
[image: Textedit displaying utf.txt]

Answer (score 0):

Since the file contents are identical, there must be something outside of the file contents that are determining how the file is interpreted. The file name is the obvious suspect. If you name the files identically in different directories, do they start behaving identically?

Use the [`file`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/file.1.html#//apple_ref/doc/man/1/file) command to see how OS/X is guessing the file type.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. See my answer for more information. BTW, file returns UTF-8 text for both files.